# Finding the x value of a certain node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to find the X values of the first and second elements in a node array, such as this one:

```
nodes = [{
x: xvalue,
y: getY(xvalue)
    }, {
x: xvalue2,
y: getY(xvalue2)
    }];
```

I thought it would be something like:

```
nodes[0].x;
```

or:

```
d3.select(".nodes").something
```

but I'm not really sure and I can't find anything about it online.

Comment: `var v = nodes[0].x;` should work just fine so read the `x` property on the first object in the array.  What's the problem with that?  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lttbms4a/.

Comment: Keep in mind that the values of those `x` and `y`. properties are set at the time the object is defined.  They are not computed dynamically based on the latest values of `xvalue` and `xvalue2` or the latest functions calls to `getY(xvalue)`.  All those values and functions are evaluated at the time the object is defined and then stored.

Comment: Well, as can be seen in https://jsfiddle.net/cuhwvj8t/, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In that jsFiddle, `makeDots()` is never called so the `nodes` array is never initialized to it's empty and thus the error your jsFiddle shows in the console.

Comment: I don't know why control F won't find it, but it's in there. I've made it a bit more noticable in https://jsfiddle.net/cuhwvj8t/1/

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in `makeDots()` and then execute your jsFiddle, the breakpoint is never hit and, sure enough, `nodes` is still an empty array.  In your jsFiddle, no code is calling `makeDots()`.

Comment: That's probably because I put in this test code:

function displayVals() {
    console.log(nodes[0].x);
}

since it works normally, as can be seen in https://jsfiddle.net/cuhwvj8t/2/

Comment: So, the last jsFiddle seems to work.  What is the question then?

Comment: I need to use the first and second element's x values in a function, but the console.log statement seems to show that nodes[0].x is improper syntax or something, and I need the right way to do it.

Comment: I added a couple `console.log()` statements to `makeDots()` in https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cuhwvj8t/3/ and the syntax you're already using works fine.  If you get errors with that syntax, then it's because the nodes array is empty at the time you try to use it and it's probably a matter of timing or something else, not a syntax issue.  The error is telling you that `nodes[0]` is undefined.  That means that first array element does not have a value.  It's not a syntax issue.  It's a matter of only reading the array after it has been populated.

Comment: Oh yeah ok that makes sense since the console log I had before did run before the initiializations. Thanks